# jQuery Display Date on Webpage

Tags: jquery, html, date

I want to display this on a webpage using jQuery...

Friday 12 August 2011

I have a div with an ID of date setup that I would like to print it into.

Jquery so far..

```
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);    
$('#Date').html((newDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + newDate.getDate() + '/' + newDate.getFullYear());
```

Can someone tell me how to format this correctly?

Comment: you are writing more code with jQuery, why not do it with PHP? Some people may not have Javascript enabled on their browsers.

Comment: @Grigor -- and where the h is php coming from?

Comment: it's a flat HTML site at the moment as the client's server doesn't support PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
var dayNames= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]

var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);    
$('#Date').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + " " + newDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/X9hyZ/

Answer (score 2):

Since your using jQuery, one of its' strengths is the plugin architecture.

So I'd just find and use a plugin for this

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

http://pablocantero.com/blog/2010/09/04/jquery-plugin-javascript-for-java-util-date-tostring-format/

```
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1); 
$('#Date').html($.format.date(newDate, 'ddd dd MMMM yyyy'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HPhDV/

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not a jQuery plugin, I've found the [Date.js library](http://www.datejs.com/) to be extremely useful for all Date formatting and parsing in JavaScript.  For your particular scenario, this code would output the formatted date:

```
Date.today().toString("dddd d MMMM yyyy")
```