# I need a line of code that updates text on a web page as per the day of the week

Tags: asp.net, date

I need a line of code that updates to todays date on a web page.
It has to sit inside an asp website.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Display Date on Webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042851/jquery-display-date-on-webpage)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Should this be done in the backend while rendering the page, or in the frontend through JS?

Answer (score 0):

Well based on the question and based on the details you've given us, the best thing I can suggest is this.

```
lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString
```

lblDate is a label into which the current date goes in.

That's a line of code that shows the current days date on a web page and it can easily "sit" inside an ASP website. If you want it to appear automatically, you may put that line of code in your Page_Load method.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString
    End Sub
```

The code is in VB.NET because I didn't see a tag for the code you're using. I think you'll get the gist of it though and you can use online converters to convert your code.

Comment: I mean as a visitor would see

Comment: Yes it should. Try it.